# Issue while reading data from a socket

Tags: c#, asyncsocket

I'm trying to send data to my server and receive it on other side but it seems like I cannot transmit the data
This is my client side code :

```
 public void SendMessage(string MessageToSend)
        {
            MessageToSend += "#-*!!|#";
            byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(MessageToSend);
        clientSocket.BeginSend(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), clientSocket);

    }

    private void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        Socket client = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        int bytesSent = client.EndSend(ar);
        Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);
    }
```

and here is my server

```
 private void ReceiveCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;

            int received = state.workSocket.EndReceive(ar);

            if (received > 0)
            {
                state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, received));
                content = state.sb.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine("RECEIVED  : " + Encoding.UTF8.GetString(state.buffer, 0, received));
                if (content.IndexOf("#-*!!|#") != -1)
                {                        StaticVariables.ReqHandler.Requests.Add(content.Substring(0, content.Length - 7));
                    state.workSocket.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), state);

                    state.sb.Clear();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    state.workSocket.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), state);
                }
            }

        }
```

The problem is I can never go into that if block which I look if the incoming message is done or not.. Can someone show me where I make a mistake?

Update :  When I use breakpoint and check the "content" variable I see alot of \0\0\0\0\0\0\0 and go on which is empty when look normally, can this be because of my buffer size or something about encoding?

Update 2 : I've just realized when I go with breakpoints on this line

```
state.sb.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(state.buffer, 0, received));
```

my state.buffer is totally empty. I'll write the beginning of my code and how I call "ReceiveCallBack". Maybe I do something wrong on previous part of the code.

```
 public void StartServer()
        {
            serverSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, port));
            serverSocket.Listen(10);
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallBack), null);
        }

        private void AcceptCallBack(IAsyncResult ar)
        {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.EndAccept(ar);
            clientSockets.Add(socket);
            StateObject State = new StateObject();
            State.workSocket = socket;
            socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), State);
            serverSocket.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallBack), null);
        }
```

This is how I start my server. I use this to call StartServer

```
StaticVariables.SocketObject = new SocketConnection();
            Thread ServerThread = new Thread(() => StaticVariables.SocketObject.StartServer());
            ServerThread.Start();
```

Comment: Does the console ever show `RECEIVED  : ...`? Does it match the data you've sent?

Comment: I see only emptiness, but I know why now but I still dont know how to solve it yet. I'll update my post

Comment: And the server does show "Sent {0} bytes to server."?

Comment: This line Console.WriteLine("Sent {0} bytes to server.", bytesSent);
produce this : Sent 38 bytes to server.

Comment: And yes console is writing RECEIVED :
thats it. Only emptiness. when I use breakpoint to look inside the variable I see full of \0's inside the variable

Comment: The reason I get full of \0's is because the buffer I use is full of zeroes. But I'm not sure how to fix it

Answer (score 0):

The client uses ASCII encoding, on the server side you use UTF8. Have you tried using the same encodings?

Comment: I might write it wrong yes, but still it should only effect my output on console. The program should be go into that if block if I had any data

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out what is wrong. On this line:

```
socket.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), State);
```

I was using variable named "buffer" which is normal. That means the data will come inside this variable. But then on ReceiveCallBack I was using this

```
state.sb.Append(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(state.buffer, 0, received));
```

Which I was not filling state.buffer so I was just encoding an empty byte array thats why I was not able to retrieve the data.. I can't believe I did not see this for hours..

Anyway I changed my beginreceive like this :

```
socket.BeginReceive(State.buffer, 0, State.buffer.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallBack), State);
```

so now I can fill the data into State object and use it on Callback..

in short be sure where u fill the incoming data :|

Comment: It had to be something not in the code you initially posted, glad you found the problem!